# Google Apps SAML SSO with deflated response from IDP

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, saml, saml-2.0

Does Google Apps - Single Sign On(SSO) supports **DEFLATE Encoding
** ? I am using an IDP that encodes the SAML response after deflating it. When this response is submitted to Google-Apps it does not allow signing in and shows the error "can not parse the login request". When deflating is disabled it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the SAML 2.0 Web SSO Profile, HTTP Deflate is not supported for the SAML Response using POST Binding. While you may receive the AuthnRequest that via the Redirect Binding that is using HTTP Deflate, you do not return the Response with that encoding. You should Base 64 Encode then URL Encode the Response for the POST Data.